# '$' gets converted to '2918 1174 2918' when executing perl

Tags: jquery, perl

I have a perl that spits  out an html page. I want to manipulate the html page using jquery. I have put all the jquery code into string and put that string inside

```
<script type='javascript'> code </script>
```

block. But when I execute perl,  all of my `$` symbols gets converted to `2918 1174 2918`.
So if my code was `$(".className")` now I get `2918 1174 2918(".className")`

Can anyone please guide me? My code is as below:

```
 my $str = "<html><head><script type='text/javascript' src='js/top5jquery-1.6.2.min.js'>";
   $str .="<script type='text/javascript'>$('.submitButton').click(function(){ alert('clicked submit button'); });";
   $str .="</head><body><input type='submit' value='submit' />Submitting</body></html>";

my $file_name = "/mainDirectory/myfile";
my $fh;
open ($fh, "> $file_name") or die "Can not open $file_name to write";
print $fh $str;
close($fh);
```

Comment: Can you post the Perl script (at least the part that spits out the HTML)? I think you aren't escaping the dollar signs.

Comment: If you omit the JavaScript bits, are you able to embed Perl code inside HTML?

Comment: sure . i am storing all html in a string and storing string contents in .html file. So my $str ="<script type='text/javascript'>$('.myClassName')</script>" gets converted <script type='text/javascript'>2918 1174 2918('.myClassName')</script> in my html file

Comment: Yes if I omit the javascript I am able to embed perl code inside HTML file. As such there is'nt any error but I am not able to use any java-script functionality.

Comment: Still waiting for you to [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8040536/edit) and add the relevant Perl code.

Comment: You forgot to close a `script` tag. Another good reason to use templates instead of embedding HTML in Perl strings.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I finally resolved the error by using /$(".className") to render $(".className") in html. Also @Sinan Ünür your answer would work too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 14):

[`$(`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#%24REAL_GROUP_ID) is a valid variable name in Perl.

It means the "real group id" of the current process, and contains a space separated list of all the group ids that the user belongs to.

To use a literal `$(...` in Perl in a context where strings are interpolated, you need to escape it, e.g.:

```
\$(".classname")
```

Answer (score 10):

You should put your HTML and JavaScript in a template to avoid these sorts of hassles. See [HTML::Template](http://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTemplate), [HTML::Zoom](http://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aZoom) and [Template Toolkit](http://metacpan.org/module/Template), among other template tools for Perl.

The immediate solution to your problem is to use:

```
my $str = q{<script type='text/javascript'>$('.myClassName')</script>};
```

or

```
my $str = <<'EO_HTML';
<html>
   <head>
     <script type='text/javascript' src='js/top5jquery-1.6.2.min.js'>
     <script type='text/javascript'>$('.submitButton').click(function(){
       alert('clicked submit button'); });
     </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <input type='submit' value='submit' />Submitting</body>
 </html>
EO_HTML
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using 'jQuery' instead of '$.' It has the same meaning and the $ is just shorthand.

Comment: +1 to cancel out the downvotes. The answer is a lame work-around alright, but it avoiding `$` does work and IMO marking this "not useful" is not justified.

Answer (score 3):

Read this [little tutorial about Perl's heredoc syntax](http://perl.about.com/od/perltutorials/qt/perlheredoc.htm). Double quoted strings do not look practical when you need to insert a full block of jQuery code.