# Does perl have an equivalent to TCLs expr within a string

Tags: perl

I have a script that writes an html page.

Much of the content is fixed and so I use print qq! to output well formatted text in a single statement.

A few of the lines need a variable + 2 embedded in them, so I have ended up pre-calculating $myVarplus2, which is OK in this one case.

```
my $myVarPlus2 = $myVar + 2;
```

In TCL I could just use [expre $myVar + 2] within the statement. Is there a similar concept for Perl ?

This is the equivalent of what I would like to do

```
print qq!
$('td:nth-child(n)').show();!
$('td:nth-child([expr $myVar + 2])').removeClass('failCount');!
```

I would rather not break the statement up

```
print qq!
$('td:nth-child(n)').show();!
$('td:nth-child(" . $myVar + 2 . qq!').removeClass('failCount');!
```

but accept it may be the simplest approach.

Comment: Gack! Careful using double quote interpolation (`"..."`, `qq/.../`) to output jQuery code. [`$(` is a valid expression in Perl.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040536/)

Comment: yes, a colleague gacked at me for that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do it, poor-man's templating in Perl strings:

```
print qq!
\$('td:nth-child(n)').show();
\$('td:nth-child(@{[ $myVar + 2 ]}).removeClass('failCount');!
```

It's up to your own judgement whether you find that more readable than breaking the statement up, and at what point it becomes difficult to maintain.

Another way to do it would be printf

```
printf q!
$('td:nth-child(n)').show();
$('td:nth-child(%s).removeClass('failCount');!, $myVar + 2;
```

But perl golf aside, unless this is a simple throwaway project, in the long run I think you'd be best served by looking at [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/), then you can write your output like this

```
$template = q!
$('td:nth-child(n)').show();
$('td:nth-child([% myVar +2 %]).removeClass('failCount');!;
```

Comment: The 1st example should be qq, otherwise the interpolation won't work. Otherwise... thanks. Live and learn.

Comment: qq indeed! Thanks for pointing that out--I fixed the 1st example.

Answer (score 2):

You could just interpolate an anonymous arrayref containing the single expression:

```
print qq!
$('td:nth-child(n)').show();!
$('td:nth-child(@{[ $myVar + 2] })').removeClass('failCount');!
```

However, mixing HTML and Perl like that is messy. I would recommend using a template module such as [HTML::Template](http://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTemplate) which would enable you to say:

```
 $tmpl->param(
     MYVAR => $myVar,
     OTHERVAR => ($myVar + 2),
 );
```

etc given a template that contains:

```
$('td:nth-child(n)').show();
$('td:nth-child(<TMPL_VAR OTHERVAR>').removeClass('failCount');
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a horrible hacky way to do this by creating an anonymous array containing your expression and deferencing the array immediately. But I really don't recommend it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $my_var = 10;

my $output = "my_var is $my_var. my_var + 2 is @{[ $my_var + 2 ]}";

say $output
```

Far better to use a real templating system. I recommend the [Template Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/release/Template-Toolkit).

Comment: One can also use a scalar reference: `my $output = "my_var is $my_var. my_var + 2 is ${\( $my_var + 2 )}";`